# Date() Only Month and Day Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

All I want is for this to work with just the day and month. I dont wanna keep copying and pasting for every year.

```
    var christmas = new Date("2020 Dec 25").toDateString();
    var today = new Date().toDateString();

    function Talk3() {
    if (today === christmas) {
    alert("Merry Christmas! I hope you have a Jolly day! I know I am.");
    }else{
    alert("Oh, Well hello. I hope your having a good day!");
    }
    }
```

Comment: `today.getMonth() == 11 && today.getDate() == 25`…?!

Comment: Also note that the string you're passing into `new Date` is not in [the format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) that `new Date` is specified to parse. **If** it parses it, you don't know whether it parses it as UTC or local time, and you don't know that it will parse it the same way cross-browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the day of year of a JavaScript Date using [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth). By passing in 11 and 25, we can check if a date is Christmas (Months are zero-based)

```js
function isDayOfYear(date, month, day) { 
    return (date.getMonth() === month) && (date.getDate() === day);
}

function isChristmas(date) {
    // Months are zero-based. 
    return isDayOfYear(date, 11, 25);
}

let testDates = [new Date("2020-12-24"), new Date("2020-12-25"), new Date("2020-12-26"), new Date("2021-12-24"), new Date("2021-12-25"), new Date("2021-12-26")];
testDates.forEach(d => console.log("IsChristmas (" + d.toDateString() + "):", isChristmas(d)));
```